# Kohain marrying divorcee

Tags: halacha, marriage, kohen-priest, heterodox, divorce

Can A Kohain marry a woman who had a reform/conservative rabbi officiate her wedding.. but she was divorced by an orthodox rabbi.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Unfortunately I have to vote to close, as this appears to be a personal request for Halachic ruling, which we cannot provide here.  It's an interesting question, though.  If you fleshed it out a bit and made it less personal I'd vote to re-open (assuming it does get closed).  The question seems to be whether it's the marriage or the divorce that matters, and whether a just-in-case divorce has the same ramifications as a regular divorce.

Comment: Brian, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing up this interesting question! To expand on what @SethJ said, if this is a practical question, it really needs to go to a rabbi who can investigate all the particulars of the situation. However, the question posted here could be [edit]ed into a more general theoretical question that it would be interesting for us to discuss here.

Comment: If I am not mistaking there is a Teshuva in the Igros Moshe regarding such.

Comment: Just because it was reform/conservative doesn't mean it was an invalid wedding. It depends on the particulars, which is why the other comments are advising you to speak to a Rabbi. The Rabbi who performed the divorce would be an excellent choice - he would know if he was doing a divorce "just in case" or because it was a valid marriage.

Comment: @Ariel Even a "just in case" _get_ will likely forbid her from a kohein, both because of safek deoraita lechumra and because of reiach haget.

Answer (score 2):

It appears from the Rambam (הלכות גירושין [פרק י](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/4210.htm) :כ-כ"ב)  and other places that once a couple behaves as husband & wife, then they need a Get to become divorced - and permitted to marry other people.

As a result, their divorce as a real one, and would disqualify her from marrying a Cohen.